# Stop Timer() in custom TextView

Tags: android, android-activity, timer

I am using customized TextView to update time frequently in ListView, that is working correctly.
The problem is that timer continuously repeating its task but activity has benn finished.

Please explain how to stop timer when activity is finished.

```
public class TextViewTimerUpdate extends TextView {

private TimerTask mTimerTask;
private Timer mTimer;
private CharSequence mRelativeTime;

public TextViewTimerUpdate(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public TextViewTimerUpdate(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TextViewTimerUpdate(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

private CharSequence mText;

public void setTextForTime(final CharSequence text) {
    mText = text;
    startTimer();
}

public void startTimer() {
    Logger.i("startTimer", "startTimer");

    stopTimer();
    mTimer = new Timer();
    mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // postInvalidate();
            Logger.i("timer", "timer");
            Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Logger.i("thread", "thread");

                    mRelativeTime = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                            Long.parseLong(mText + ""), 
                            System.currentTimeMillis()
                            , 0);

                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                }
            });
            th.run();
        }
    };
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mTimerTask, 0, 8000);
}

    public void stopTimer() {

        if (mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.cancel();
            mTimer = null;
        }

    }

private void justSetText(CharSequence text) {
    Logger.e("justSetText", text + "");
    super.setText(text + "", null);
}

private Handler handler = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        justSetText(mRelativeTime);
    };
};

}
```

Comment: Timer = Thread, in TimerTask you create another Thread, thank god you call  th.run(); instead of  th.star(); and all of it for updating simple text, what a waste. instead just use one simple Handler with sentEmptyMessageDelayed or even View.postDelayed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the `onDetachedFromWindow()` method in your custom `TextView`, and call `stopTimer()` in there.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make a 2nd handler and within that handler call your `stopTimer()`.

Alternatively you can decide to use an `AsyncTask`. Then you can call the `stopTimer()` in the `onPostExecute()` method